# Innodb: When bulk inserting or updating - how to disable transactions?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, transaction-log

When doing a mass insert like `INSERT INTO SELECT FROM` the speed benefit of doing that in chunks of 10k records can be enormous, in my tests a query that was running for 5 days took only 2 hours using the chunk method.

To make things worse: if you let such an operation run for a few hours and KILL the job (or crash) then it can take days or weeks until ROLLBACK is finished.
Rollback is significantly slower than insert, no optimizations here.

The same counts for doing mass UPDATEs.

**My question:**
How can I completely disable transaction log for such a transactions ?

I tested this:    `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`
But it showed no difference, when killing the job transactions start rolling back.

I really did my homework and tried to find anything about it, no luck.

P.S.
Of course I am aware that importing without transactions does not give a unique snapshot to rely on if anything is changed in meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot turn off transactions.

It is assumed that `ROLLBACK` is the exception, not the rule.  Are you trying to make it the "normal" path?

5 days vs 2 hours -- this is far more extreme than I would expect.  Perhaps you are running out of RAM?  Or swapping?

Please provide more details on the task; we may be able to help you 'solve' the problem in a way other than "turning off transactions".

Comment: Well it's half a billion records I was testing this with, and I have larger tables than that.
64GB of ram was used when I had that tested, no swapping but that table was half a terrabyte, I don't have that RAM.

The problem is really the transaction. I wrote a stored procedure that does it in 10k rows "parts" and it was finished after 1.5 hours.
The full dataset would take a week without separating it into parts. It's the transaction log causing this.

Comment: `innodb_log_file_size` may also be a factor.

Comment: Hmm, a small innodb_log_file_size would stop the rollback problem right ?
But the performance problem probably not, correct ?

I don't know what mysql is doing when it creates a transaction of 500 million rows. But whatever it is, it's roughly 100 times slower in comparison to forcing small transactions.

Comment: @John - it would not stop the rollback, but changing the size might speed it up.

Comment: @John - It starts by putting rollback stuff in the log file.  But you have too much for that, so it overflows and starts putting it in with the rows.  This backup strategy is more costly, hence slower (than if you chunked, `COMMITting` after each chunk).  But 60x diff in speed is far more than I would expect.

Comment: I understand, I didn't know it puts it into the main file.
It is quite uncommon to deal with such large tables on mysql in general, the vast majority of users have small tables with few columns and not too many rows.
I found quite a few people reporting about similar behaviour, also reporting about days of inserting.
One guy reported he was able to speed up a 7 day insert to 30 minutes by splitting up in chunks.

Comment: great, finding my own question half a year later :) Issue is now 4 times as large with the table having 4 TB not 1 TB. 
Copying that thing is like moving an ocean with a shovel. 
I guess Oracle time is approaching

Comment: @John - Does Oracle have magically faster disk drives?